# How to open up the Messages app via an Ionic 1 app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I know for a fact that having a link like this for example: `<a href="sms://12345">send message to 12345</a>` will open up the Messages app with a prepended number `12345` and a way to start writing a new message to that number.

I can’t seem to figure out how to just open the list of all the messages, without sending in the number. If I do it like this: `<a href="sms://">open Messages</a>` then nothing happens when you click the link.

It could be that this is not at all possible, but then again, I'd like someone to confirm that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sms://12345` Is a *deep link* that sends referrer to `sms` application with value `12345`. The Messages App redirects you to activity regards to content.

If  Messages App doesn't support empty deep link (a.e. `sms://`) - you have nothing to do with that.

for example [Manifest.xml of Messages App](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/+/3f9821128abd66c4cd2f040d8243efb334bfad2d/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="mms" />
    <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I guess I'll be closing this ticket as WNI (will not implement). Will accept the answer after the grace period is over - thanks!